# Using newline as a separator with numpy.savetxt not working

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing the following command:

```
 np.savetxt('File1', File1, delimiter = ',\n')
```

The problem is when I open File1 in NotePad (Windows), all the numerical values I calculated come out on one line. I want each data value to start on a new line.

For example, I get: 123456

```
  instead of:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5 
  6
```

I have tried using delimiter and newline in parameters but no luck.

Note: this does work if I open WordPad but not NotePad for some reason.

Comment: try`np.savetxt('File1', File1, newline='\n')`

Comment: This might be an issue with NotePad itself: https://superuser.com/a/362092.

You can try delimiting by `os.linesep` instead.

Comment: Why do you want the comma? `,\n`? You may want to try `'\r\n'` instead, CRLF is what Windows uses for line separators.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @Harsha I thought I tried every combination of newline and delimiter but you found my solution. Thank you! And thank you all for suggesting solutions, it is appreciated!

Comment: @NEMM2020 welcome :) you can accept my answer :)

Comment: I am sorry I meant @COLDSPEED your solution worked. I thought I had Harsha 's solution in my code. Regardless, thank you both!

Comment: Oh, you're welcome.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake @Harsha I am not sure why your solution did not work, I would have never guessed '\r \n' either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, the separator is CRLF (carriage return + line feed). You can use `\r\n` as a separator.

```
np.savetxt(..., newline='\r\n')
```

Alternatively, without loss in generality, import `os` and use `os.linesep`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781815/easy-numpy-savetxt-function-but-delimiter-not-working/48782059#comment84565043_48781815) by @SeanBreckenridge. This would be the best option in terms of portability.

```
import os
np.savetxt(..., newline=os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
np.savetxt('File1', File1, newline='\r\n')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.